# Android: Static value in activity needs to be accessed by other activities

Tags: android, android-activity, static, organization

I have a static value in a mainActivity.java that needs to be accessed through multiple activities. What is the best way to do this? I can only think of one way to implement this. I never "finish()" the mainActivity.java. Other activities that are spawned from mainActivity that access the static value are finished though. I am a novice to android programming so all the help is appreciated.

Comment: just use `mainActivity.value` in other activitys or you can store `value` in `sharedpreference`.

Comment: use sharedpreference if your value type is built in.

Comment: You should describe your problem in more detail, either a sharedpreference, *or* a service, *or* a content provider (internal), *or* a number of other things could be applicable depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static attribute does not belong to any instance but the class itself.

And the static value will persist even after the activity is finished.

So you can access a static value of the activity by

```
int value = MainActivity.value;
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Another question to follow this up. So if mainActivity is destroyed or paused, the static value will still exist ,correct?

Comment: Yes, the static value will still exist until the process is over(i.e. the whole app is closed)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the value to other activity or put the static value in the `Application`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for more reliable performance.

Alternately you can have a Utility class to hold all static members that you want to use across the whole app any time.

If you decide that this answers your question, please mark it as "accepted". This will raise both your and my reputation score.